# jquery colorbox: get parameters after close colorbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have parent page `parent.html` like below to call a colorbox:

```
 <script src="colorbox/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".example7").colorbox({
            width:"60%", 
            height:"40%", 
            iframe:true
            });

         //How I can get Parameters from ColorBox when ColorBox closed
 </script>

<body>
    <p><a class='example7' href="demo_01.html">Click here to open Colorbox</a></p>
</body>
```

And on the `demo_01.html`, I have 2 Images

```
 <html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function onChooseAndClose(val){
      //how to setup to sent paramters (ID of image was chosen) to parent page before close colorbox
      ......
      //close this Colorbox
      parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()

   }
 </script>
<body>
   <img src="imamges/img1.png" id="idImg1" onclick="javascript:onChooseAndClose('idImg1');" />
   <img src="imamges/img2.png" id="idImg2" onclick="javascript:onChooseAndClose('idImg2');" />

</body>
</html>
```

In parent.html, How I can get Parameters from [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) when ColorBox closed

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Override the close function of Colorbox with your own.

```
var originalClose = $.colorbox.close;
$.colorbox.close = function(){
    var response;
    if($('#cboxLoadedContent').find('form').length > 0){
       response = confirm('Do you want to close this window?');
       if(!response){
          return; // Do nothing.
       }
    }
    originalClose();
};
```

Here we are getting the original close method. 
And we are override that method to do our scripting then finally we are calling the original Close method.